# java security issue

Tags: java, java-service-wrapper

I try to run derby database as windows service using java service wrapper ([JSW](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp)). I downloaded community edition `3.5.15`.

there is wrapper config I use:

```
wrapper.java.command=java
#wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperStartStopApp

wrapper.java.classpath.1=../lib/derby.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=../lib/derbynet.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3=../lib/derbytools.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.4=Wrapper.jar

wrapper.java.library.path.1=

wrapper.java.additional.1=-Dderby.system.home=c:/data/derby

#wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl
#wrapper.app.parameter.2=start

wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl
wrapper.app.parameter.2=3
wrapper.app.parameter.3=start
wrapper.app.parameter.4=-h
wrapper.app.parameter.5=127.0.0.1
wrapper.app.parameter.6=org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl
wrapper.app.parameter.7=true
wrapper.app.parameter.8=1
wrapper.app.parameter.9=shutdown
wrapper.console.format=PM
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO
wrapper.logfile=log/wrapper.log
wrapper.logfile.format=LPTM
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=5m
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=10
wrapper.syslog.loglevel=ERROR

wrapper.console.title=Derby DB Server
wrapper.ntservice.name=derby
wrapper.ntservice.displayname=Apache Derby Database
wrapper.ntservice.description=Apache Derby Relational Database Engine (Network Server)
wrapper.ntservice.starttype=AUTO_START
wrapper.ntservice.interactive=false
#wrapper.ntservice.account=.\derby
#wrapper.ntservice.password=derbypw
```

and when I try to start derby server via wrapper I get security violation exception:

```
c:\derby\bin>wrapper -c derby.conf
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Java Service Wrapper Community Edition 32-bit 3.5.15
wrapper  |   Copyright (C) 1999-2012 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
wrapper  |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
wrapper  |
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | WrapperManager: Initializing...
jvm 1    | Sun Jul 22 22:11:11 BST 2012 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
jvm 1    | Sun Jul 22 22:11:11 BST 2012 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.9.1.0 - (1344872) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527
jvm 1    | WrapperManager Error: Error in WrapperListener.start callback.  java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.security.WrapperPerm
ission signalStarting)
jvm 1    | WrapperManager Error: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.security.WrapperPermission signalStarting)
jvm 1    | WrapperManager Error:        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    | WrapperManager Error:        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    | WrapperManager Error:        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    | WrapperManager Error:        at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.signalStarting(WrapperManager.java:3268)
jvm 1    | WrapperManager Error:        at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperStartStopApp.start(WrapperStartStopApp.java:437)
jvm 1    | WrapperManager Error:        at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager$11.run(WrapperManager.java:3963)
jvm 1    | WrapperManager Error: Unable to remove the Wrappers shudownhook: {0}
jvm 1    | Exception in thread "WrapperListener_start_runner" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.security.WrapperPermission signal
Stopped)
jvm 1    |      at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.signalStopped(WrapperManager.java:3320)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.shutdownJVM(WrapperManager.java:4058)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.privilegedStopInner(WrapperManager.java:4363)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.access$2900(WrapperManager.java:124)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager$11.run(WrapperManager.java:3983)
wrapper  | CTRL-C trapped.  Shutting down.
wrapper  | Shutdown failed: Timed out waiting for signal from JVM.
wrapper  | JVM did not exit on request, terminated
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I could add permission grant to java.policy to solve this problem (I have not tried, but suppose that will work).

The thing I want to know is: what enforces security constraints (and throws security exception) in this case? I thought that all locally started java application are granted all permissions.

One more thing that confuses me: I have h2 database server (1.3.162 (2011-11-26)) running via JSW (but earlier version) there are no security grants for it. I searched for *.policy files containing `wrapper` word, and there was nothing. How in this case security is configured, and if it is configured at all?

I would be grateful if someone make these security issues more clear :P.

Comment: As your logging output shows, some part of your system (probably Derby, looking at your logs) installs a Security Manager - this is what enforces the constraints. A Security Manager doesn't _have_ to use a .policy file - it can be configured programmatically or hard-coded.

Comment: @DNA, seems I understand. derby installs some security manager which policy is more restrictive for wrapper to run. This also explains why h2 runs perfectly without additional configuration.

Comment: When you run with the Wrapper, the Wrapper classes are launching your application's main method.  This is inserting classes from the wrapper.jar into the call stack.  Java's security model works by limiting access to the permissions granted to the weakest method in the call stack.

In order to make this work, you will need to give classes in the wrapper.jar permission to do what you want.  This is described on our site here:
http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/security-model.html

Answer (score 1):

Putting Leif's comment as answer:

When you run with the Wrapper, the Wrapper classes are launching your application's main method. This is inserting classes from the wrapper.jar into the call stack. Java's security model works by limiting access to the permissions granted to the weakest method in the call stack. In order to make this work, you will need to give classes in the wrapper.jar permission to do what you want.

This is described on our site here:

http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/security-model.html